# why isnt this working?(its supposed to print if a number is prime or not)

Tags: python

```
ok=0

n=int(input())

for x in range(2,n/2):
    if n%x==0:
        ok==1

if (ok==1):
    print("its a prime")

else:
    print("its not a prime")
```

Comment: Youre checking if ok is 1, not assigning.

Comment: Change ok==1 to ok=1

Comment: `range(2,n/2)` only works with python2 but you use python3 `print()` syntax

Comment: Other than many other issues, this `ok==1` should be `ok = 1`.

Comment: if i put : if(ok=1) it says:File "/home/luca/c++/.vscode/ded.py", line 7
    if (ok=1):
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: @Drake - you changed the wrong line

Comment: Please take a basic Python tutorial (again) as this should sort out your questions and issues.

Comment: 2 more things on top of the issue from the question:

1) You can consider using a `break` after assigning 1 to `ok`, as there is no need to check any more number if we already have `ok == 1`.
2) If `ok` is set to `1`, it means that the number is not a prime.

Comment: @MaciejCzarnecki - Nice debugging: Every answer is wrong, nobody actually checked their solution.

Answer (score 2):

1. This line

   ```
    ok==1
   ```

is a comparison, not an assignment. To assign `1` to `ok`, you have to use a single equal mark.

2. After assigning `1` to `ok`, you can use a `break`, as there is no need to check further.
3. If `ok` is set to `1`, then it means that the number is not a prime, so you have to swap the printed messages.

Answer (score 1):

In your for cicle you have to assign 1 to ok, so only one = needed

```
ok=0

n=int(input())

for x in range(2,n/2):
    if n%x==0:
        ok=1

if (ok==1):
    print("its a prime")

else:
    print("its not a prime")
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove one of the `"="` in the line `ok==1`.
At the moment ok will never == 1.

Answer (score 0):

```
ok=0

n=int(input())

for x in range(1,int(n/2)):
  if n%x==0:
    ok=1

if (ok==1):
    print("its a prime")
else:
    print("its not a prime")
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation of what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality.